# Jasper report: disable pdf toolbar when generating a pdf

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

Is it possible to disable the pdf toolbar when generating a pdf from a Jasper Report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your PDF being opened by an external PDF Reader, like Adobe or Foxit?
If so, then I don't think so, this is the toolbar of the application itself.

On the other hand you can use PDF Viewer, a viewer that comes integrated with JasperReports. This one you can control. But then you will limit the user if he wants to do anything with the PDF.

In my own experience, I way keep it. If you remove it, the customer will soon ask for tools to zoom in and out, and maybe even to annotate.

Comment: Hi Medopal

Thank you for the reply.

Currently the pdf is being exported to a new browser tab. Reason why I want to remove the toolbar is because the report is only for viewing, dont want the user to be able to print or save from the document. 

Any suggestions how to go about this?

Comment: if it's a browser window, then you are using the browser plugin for viewing PDF, which will use the default PDF viewer on the machine. Like Adobe Reader or Foxit. I don't think you will be able to export to browser window without toolbar. On the other hand you can popup a special dialog using the JasperViewer